# How call a function, when the user confirms the question?

Tags: elisp, functions

I'm trying to write some Emacs Lisp. But I stumble on one thing. 
The code is structured as following:

```
(defun foo ()
    (interactive)
    (if (yes-or-no-p "Do you want to call the function bar?")
        (progn 
            'bar
            ))
            )


(defun bar (string)
  (interactive "sType your input here? ")
  (message string))
```

Okay, when the user confirms the question, the function bar will be called. But nothing happens when I press <kbd>y</kbd>.

When reading the Elisp cookbooks and tutorials, they all says that `yes-or-no-p` functions returns a true when the user confirmed it.
And the `if` is structured as following:

```
COND THEN ELSE
```

So the second argument should be calling since `yes-or-no-p` evaluates to true. Since this seems not the case, I'm missing something?

Comment: `(progn 'bar)` does not invoke function `bar`. `C-h i`, choose `Emacs Lisp Intro`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To call `bar`, use `(bar "string")` or `(call-interactively 'bar)` depending on how you want to specify the argument of `bar`.